# MySQL query is extremely long from PHP

Tags: php, mysql, query-optimization

I have a query that takes 0.0002s in PHPMyAdmin and takes hundreds of seconds if I do it from PHP. Here it is:

```
    SELECT  id, id_pages, link, childlink, url, hiddencontent, cansearch,
        (
            SELECT  p.id
                FROM  pages as p
                WHERE  pages.hiddencontent=1
                  AND  p.id_pages IS NOT NULL
                  AND  p.hiddencontent=0
                  AND  pages.id=p.id_pages
                order by  p.npp asc
                limit  1
        ) as id_firstchild
        FROM  pages
```

It returns around 24k rows and I don't know why it takes so long. My friend tried it on his PC and it worked lightning fast and his pc is not better. I don't know the reason of this PHP behavior, maybe I should make some changes in the configuration file?

Comment: PHPMyAdmin shows and fetches only few first rows. You have now shown your PHP code, but fetching 24k rows may take some time to fetch and to display, if you fetch them all. To improve future questions, show your PHP code and EXPLAIN from the query with table definitions.

Comment: Please read this https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info. Then please [edit] your question.  And keep in mind that phpmyadmin appends `LIMIT 50` or something similar to every query it runs.

Comment: 24k rows is a lot. Do you really have to work with all of them at once?

Comment: @el-vanja yes, the script I use is creating URL for the website so it takes all the rows I have in the table. The thing is that it works somewhere really fast but not on my PC so I thought maybe someone knows why it's happening

Comment: Are you really looking to display 24k URLs in your page?

Comment: Please use two different aliases on the two copies of `pages`.  It is currently unclear which `pages` that `pages.hiddencontent` is referring to.

Comment: Do you really want to deliver all 24K rows to the client?  Choke, choke.  Is the "Query cache" turned on?  That's about the only way it can run in 0.2ms.  (Any non-trivial `SELECT` that runs in under 1ms almost certainly did not run, but was found in that cache.)

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you try to decide if searching or fetching is slow, use a `LIMIT 1` at the end of your query (and comment out the `ORDER BY` part if there's any). This way, you get the first row so you will know how long that takes. It should be blazing fast.

Another useful information is when you enclose the whole query in another, like `SELECT ...FROM (SELECT ...)`, in which case the outer query should count the rows returned. This will give you the total time needed to identify all rows that *would be* fetched, but without actually fetching them. This is useful to determine if you wrote your SQL query poorly, or it's just a lot of data to fetch. (If both of the above go fast and you still get a slow query, it's the fetch.)

You can also make use of `EXPLAIN` to see if your performance issue is because of insufficient or improper indexing.

As for phpmyadmin, the first comment on your post pretty much sums it up: phpmyadmin uses a LIMIT so it will run faster even if your query itself is slow.

Comment: I suggest that phpmyadmin uses `LIMIT` because it does not want to choke your browser by trying to show you a million rows.  Also, when there is an `ORDER BY` that cannot be handled by an index, it must fetch all the rows; the `LIMIT` has very little impact in this case.

Comment: @RickJames Both statements are true. The latter is something I will add to my answer because someone with an ORDER BY might be surprised to see no significant change in speed.

Answer (score 0):

You have two questions:

**Why the timing?**

Is the "Query cache" turned on? That's about the only way it can run in 0.2ms. (Any non-trivial SELECT that runs in under 1ms almost certainly did not run, but was found in that cache.)

And, as pointed out by others, phpmyadmin silently adds a `LIMIT`.  However, other clues (mostly in Comments) point to the Query cache giving anomalous results.

**How to speed up.**

```
SELECT  id, id_pages, link, childlink, url, hiddencontent, cansearch,
        if (hiddencontent = 1, NULL,   -- to avoid doing the SELECT
            ( SELECT  p.id
                FROM  pages as p
                WHERE  p.hiddencontent = 0
                  AND  outer.id = p.id_pages -- fails on NULL
                order by  p.npp asc
                limit  1
           )) as id_firstchild
    FROM  pages AS outer    -- clarify which is which
```

and have this 'composite' and 'covering' index:

```
INDEX(hiddencontent, id_pages, npp, id)
```

Two improvements:

- Avoid calling the subquery when not needed.
- Have an index that will allow the subquery to look at only one row, and only in the index's BTree, hence be 'blazingly fast'.